# Fourier transform and Z transform question?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

Let's suppose we have an exercise where I have to find the $Z$-transform and its region of convergence. I find the $Z$-transform and the region. How do I determine if the Fourier transform exists from this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fourier transform is simply the $z$ transform evaluated at $z = e^{i\omega}$.

Thus, the Fourier transform exists iff $z = e^{i\omega}$ is in the region of convergence for all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.

This means that we just need the unit circle to be in the region of convergence.

Comment: Thank you very much,kind sir.